# How to completely reset a UITableViewController while still on screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my app, I have a very custom `UITableView`. The cells are all statically defined in Interface Builder, but based on the data structure the table morphs in many various ways. For example, if some data doesn't exist, some cells (or entire sections) are not displayed, custom separator lines are added to account for missing cells, extra views are loaded into the cells, VoiceOver labels change, etc. Because all the cells are static, I set up the table layout in `viewDidLoad` because I always have the data available at that time. I have always presented this view controller modally, which has worked great. If the user wants to display different data in this table they have to dismiss the view controller and pick a different item to present it again, and it gets rendered appropriately in all cases.

But now I am converting this into a split view controller for iPad, so this `UITableViewController` never disappears off screen, but I need to set up the table again when the user taps an item. The problem is, because the table is never deallocated, its previous layout still exists when I load more data into it. It would be a lot of work (and an excellent opportunity for many difficult to reproduce bugs to pop up) to test all possible scenarios and try to reset it back to its "pre viewDidLoad state" or undo those previous layout changes if not relevant anymore, if not impossible because I don't have references to the many different custom separator lines generated.

My question is, **is it possible to completely reset the table view controller** every time a row is selected in the master view controller, therefore allowing it to properly set up the layout because it is not stuck with the previous layout?

I essentially need some way to completely wipe it clean as if it never did any setup, then instantiate it again to cause `viewDidLoad` get called (or I can move that code to its own method or `viewWillAppear`). I'm basically looking for a way to reset the `tableView` back to how it is defined in Interface Builder.

I believe this would result in a flash because the table would completely disappear then reappear in a different format, but that would be acceptable. If that can be animated that'd be nice. If this is *really* not recommended at all, how do you suggest I proceed to ensure the layout is always appropriate for the data it is presenting?

Comment: All you should need to do is swap data sources and do a reload operation.

Comment: That would work if the code existed in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` but it is not - it's in `viewDidLoad` because the cells are all static.

Comment: Well, implement cellForRow and related methods.  Should be no biggie if you already have the logic worked out in viewDidLoad.

Comment: That won't work, because I dynamically remove cells or sections based on the data, and I add custom UIViews for separator lines in different locations based on which cells are visible in the table.

Comment: Well, the standard mechanism would handle removing cells and sections quite easily.  Dunno about the custom UIViews -- I don't even know how you'd get that to work without mucking up the table view.

Comment: (Actually, I *do* know how to handle dynamic separator lines, since I've done it.  You create a narrow cell with the appropriate color.  You need to do your bookkeeping right so you include the cell in your count, but not rocket science.)

Comment: Exactly, the table view is very mucked up. That's why I want to reset its layout before loading more data into it. :) The way I create separator lines is to display no separator lines then add my own subviews to the appropriate cells. I believe I'd still have to manually remove those even if I implemented `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: You make the separators *be* cells, just narrow ones.  (Be sure to check out ALL of the methods in the two table view delegate protocols.)  (You'll end up with something simpler than what you have now, and easier to maintain.)

Comment: If possible I'd much rather not recreate this very involved dynamic layout which is working perfectly for iPhone using a completely different approach.

Comment: Well, then, create a new VC, populate it, show it, and dispose of the old one.  But that is, as they used to say, "Throwing good money after bad".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was over-thinking this. There's really no need to completely throw away the table and generate a new one. It turned out to be simpler than I had thought to reset the table back to its default state. Just had to be sure to catch every possible thing that could change, including VoiceOver labels, and reset to `nil` or the default value. Then it can run through the reset code then the layout code every time the data changes and render an appropriate layout. The most difficult part was to remove the custom separator lines, which I solved by adding each one to an array when it's created, then index through it and remove each one from its superview then remove the Autolayout constraints associated with it. One can wrap all of this into a `UIView` animation block to get a nice fading effect. It's working quite well.